# How to calculate Geometric median of some points in x-y plane

Tags: geometry

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) I found about Geometric median. But i am still unable to calculate Geometric median of some `points (x, y)`. Can some body please calculate Geometric median by giving an example? For an example, let say i have six points `a(-3,0), b(-2,0), c(-1,0), d(0,0), e(10,0), f(50,0)`. So what is the Geometric median of these points? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try out the computation algorithm described in the wikipedia article you referred to?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median#Definition) is the Definition of Geometric median. I didn't get the formula.

Comment: Harald is pointing out that the Computation paragraph of the Wikipedia essay seems to answer your question. What part of the discussion there are you finding difficult?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Okay.... actually i was concentrating on _Definition_ paragraph.

Comment: Huh? Your question is about *calculating* the geometric median, not about defining it. So now I'm confused - what is it you really want to know? When you decide, maybe you could edit your question so it accords with what you actually want to ask.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: i have calculated it by calculating centroid first.

Comment: So why do you say in your question that you are unable to calculate it? It seems you don't really have a question.

Comment: Nope. that is not the case. currently i am first calculating `centroid` of the points, then going to calculate `Geometric median`. I thought that there should be any other way to calculate `Geometric median`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not with you. If you have a way to calculate the geometric median by first calculating the centroid, then your question shouldn't say "I am still unable to calculate the geometric median." And I still don't know whether, asked Harald asked, you tried out the algorithm in the wikipedia article.

Comment: Ohhh... Come on man... anyway, do you know about any other way for calculating `Geometric median`?

Comment: I don't know *any* way to calculate the geometric median. I know Harald has pointed you toward a way, and I infer that you aren't happy with that way, but I don't know what you find unsuitable about the wikipedia way. Also, if you want to be certain I will see your comments, please preface them with @Gerry.

Comment: I expand a little on the Wikipedia entry at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401128/how-can-i-find-an-optimal-point-on-a-scatter-graph/1401262#1401262

Answer (score 3):

What I do (crude but still helpful): Find median of data along X axis, find median of data along Y axis. This gives me coordination of "quite good estimatiom" of true geometric median. You can do the procedure to obtain means, however with simulations I found that using median is usually more correct.

I know this is very crude method, hope it helped you.